# Copy longer string to shorter string in C

Tags: c, string, strcpy

For the code below, why don't I get a seg fault or some other error/warning, since *my_dest* is declared with only 1 char?

Doesn't it go over boundary?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *MyStrcpy(char* dest, const char* src);

int main(void)
{
    char my_src[] = "1234567890";
    char my_dest[1];
    MyStrcpy(my_dest, my_src);
    printf("new dest: %s\n", my_dest);
}

char *MyStrcpy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    char* addr = dest;
    while (*dest++ = *src++);
    return addr;
}
```

Comment: "undefined behavior" != "instant crash always". this is getting really boring.

Comment: Unless this is being done entirely for educational purposes, don't write your own string routines. Just use the secure versions of the functions that came with your compiler.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn - What are you talking about?  ( _secure versions of the functions_ )

Comment: In the case of Microsoft platforms that would be: [strcpy_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx). Most of the 'original' C string library methods have lots of security risks due to buffer overruns.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: Leave me alone with their deprecation crusade and such nuisances.

Comment: Malware is a bit more than a damn nuisance... In any case, my point was "roll your own" string functions is a bad idea. In most case "undefined behavior" is "potential exploit"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program invokes undefined behavior as you are writing past the end of an array.

In C undefined behavior means anything can happen: your program can crash or crash every Thursday.

C does not require the compiler to issue a warning if the program invokes undefined behavior as it may be very difficult for the compiler to detect all the undefined behavior invocations. However C allows the compiler to issue a warning or to stop the translation but doesn't require it.

Comment: Nicely stated.  Can also be summarized with some humor in two words:  ***[nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)***.